# Extracting in words in tags in PYTHON

Tags: python, regex

Hello I'd like to extract the content of this tag

```
<Sentiment int=6>Deep injustice</Sentiment>
```

in many sentences of text ([Here](https://n0paste.tk/zBmG4MU/)).

```
df['text'].str.extractall(r'^<(?P<Sentiments>\w+).*[int]?.*(?P<Intensite>\d?\d)>(?P<Expression>[a-zA-Z]*?.*[a-zA-Z]*)<')
```

My code produce only few of them(tag). Why it do not extract others?

```
                  Sentiments Intensite               Expression
      match                                                    
405   0         Disagreement         3    Bizarre contradiction
921   0         Satisfaction         5           La plus simple
2549  0      Dissatisfaction         3     Ne me contentant pas
```

Comment: Does it have to be with regex? For such operations DOM-operations would be much better!

Comment: Hello, Could you be more clear, with a code or more explanation.

Comment: You would really benefit from a XML/DOM parser. This has been asked and answered plenty of times in a number of different programming languages. If you post your programming language I'm sure more people will be willing / able to help you.

Comment: I'm on Python , I've changed the title.
any link pleas?

Comment: That is neither XML nor HTML. Try `.extractall(r'<(?P<Sentiments>\w+)\s+int=(?P<Intensite>\d+)>(?P<Expression>[^<]*)')`, see https://regex101.com/r/a6aJ0L/1

Comment: Thank you. Let me check.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df['text'].str.extractall(r'<(?P<Sentiments>\w+)\s+int=(?P<Intensite>\d+)>(?P<Expression>[^<]*)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6aJ0L/1).

**Details**

- `<` - a `<` char
- `(?P<Sentiments>\w+)` - Group "Sentiments": 1 or more letters, digits, underscores
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace
- `int=` - a substring
- `(?P<Intensite>\d+)` - Group "Intensite": 1+ digits
- `>` - a `>` char
- `(?P<Expression>[^<]*)` - Group "Expression": 0 or more chars other than `>`